# PHP - Convert a multidimensional array to string?

Tags: php

I'm working on a small ajax application and need to see if the values being generated in the background are what is expected.  The value returned by the quest can be quite a complex multidimensional array, is there a way to convert this into a string so that it can be shown with alert?

Is there any other way of seeing these values?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

[`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r), [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) or [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) are good candidates. When writing a REST service, you might also want to look at [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Comment: output of var_export can be saved to a variable: 
$a = array (1, 2, array ("a", "b", "c"));
$b = var_export($a, true);
echo $b;

Answer (score 7):

If you want to show it with javascript, I would recommend [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), everything else has been covered by knittl's answer.

Answer (score 4):

i work on a bunch of ajax apps.. in firefox i have an "add-on" called JSON view

then all my projects have a function

```
function test_array($array) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($array);
    exit();
}
```

so whenever i want to see what the output is i just go `test_array($something)` and it shows me the results.

[image: screenshot]

its made debugging a breaze now

PS. know this Q is ancient and im not really answering the origional posters Q but might be useful for someone else aswell

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(<?=print_r($array)?>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this function useful:

```
function array2str($array, $pre = '', $pad = '', $sep = ', ')
{
    $str = '';
    if(is_array($array)) {
        if(count($array)) {
            foreach($array as $v) {
                $str .= $pre.$v.$pad.$sep;
            }
            $str = substr($str, 0, -strlen($sep));
        }
    } else {
        $str .= $pre.$array.$pad;
    }

    return $str;
}
```

from this address:
http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2008/02/04/php-array-to-string/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple answer in PHP:

```
function implode_recur($separator, $arrayvar) {
    $output = "";
    foreach ($arrayvar as $av)
    if (is_array ($av)) 
        $out .= implode_recur($separator, $av); // Recursive array 
    else                   
        $out .= $separator.$av;

    return $out;<br>
}

$result = implode_recur(">>",$variable);
```

Comment: several typos here...within implode_recur, the reference to implode_r should be implode_recur.Also change the two instances of $out to $output. This will also addthe separator string before the first element in the array ...">>a>>b>>" which may not be desirable in all cases.

Comment: This works. Just need to update the `$out` variables to `$output`.

Answer (score -1):

The [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) command returns an array as a string.

Comment: This is fine for a single array, but does not work out of the box with multidimensional arrays. You would need to loop through each array.

Answer (score -3):

you can also consider FirePHP
http://www.firephp.org